# Access JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, hook.io

```
header = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }  
url = 'https://sandbox-authservice.priaid.ch/login'
response = requests.post(url, headers = header, verify=False).json()
token = json.dumps(response)
print token['ValidThrough']
```

I want to print the ValidThrough Attribute in my webhook, which is received as JSON data via a POST call. I know this has been asked a number of times here, but print token['ValidThrough']isnt working for me.I receive the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: yes it is returning value too, it has two attributes, 'Token' and 'ValidThrough'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the response already seems to be in json, there is no need to use `json.dumps`.

`json.dumps` on a dictionary will return a string which cannot be indexed obviously and hence that error.

Answer (score 0):

a requests response `.json()` method already loads the content of the string to json.

You should use that, but your code later serializes it back to a string, and hence the error (`token` is a string representation of the dict you are expecting, not the dict). You should just omit the `json.dumps(response)` line, and use `response['ValidThrough']`

There's another error here, even if you assume that the `.json()` returns a string that should be unserialized again you should've used `json.loads(response)` in order to load it into a dict (not dumps to serialize it again)